# ¿Cómo restar valores de 2 consultas sql diferentes?

Tags: mysql

No he podido encontrar la forma de cómo restar valores de 2 consultas sql diferentes, com campos coincidentes.

La primera consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT local, mes, SUM(venta) 
FROM ventas
WHERE idProducto IN ('cod1','cod2','cod3')
GROUP BY local, mes
```

---

La segunda consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT local, mes, SUM(venta)
FROM ventas
WHERE idProducto IN ('cod6','cod7','cod8')
GROUP BY local, mes
```

Lo que necesito es restar los campos `SUM(ventas)` de cada consulta, donde sean concordante el local y el mes.

Comment: Esto donde lo estás haciendo ? en php, phpmyadmin, o algun otro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una subconsulta en el FROM, agrupando por local y mes y sumando las ventas si es del id de producto deseado, sino es el id deseado sumas 0. Posteriormente utilizas esta tabla para realizar la resta de los totales obtenidos, algo como:

```
SELECT
    tbl.local,
    tbl.mes,
    sum(tbl.venta_1) - sum(tbl.venta_2) as total
FROM
(SELECT
    local, 
    mes, 
    IF (idProducto IN ('cod1','cod2', 'cod3'), sum(venta),0) AS venta_1,
    IF (idProducto IN ('cod6','cod7', 'cod8'), sum(venta),0) AS venta_2,
FROM
    ventas
WHERE 
    idProducto IN ('cod1','cod2','cod3', 'cod6','cod7','cod8')
GROUP BY local, mes
) AS tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT local, mes, 
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN idProducto IN ('cod1','cod2','cod3') THEN venta
    WHEN idProducto IN ('cod6','cod7','cod8') THEN (-1) * venta
    END)
) FROM ventas 
WHERE idProducto IN ('cod1','cod2','cod3','cod6','cod7','cod8') 
GROUP BY local, mes
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Explica brevemente el funcionamiento de esta consulta (pulsando en [edit]): ten en cuenta que puede que no todos comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer].

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias por responder @jablamas, solo una consulta, despues del END) , sigue venta)... eso esta de sobra? verdad?.

Comment: totalmente correcto, se me escapó @OscarSantander